# Apache not serving pages

Tags: apache

I have just done a clean install of apache on RedHat. In the httpd.conf file, I have changed the ServerName to the IP address of the computer. From the command line, when I use xdg-open I cannot view the test page from the apache server (when using the public IP in the address bar), however I can see it when I open 127.0.0.1. 
I have a rule in my firewall to allow traffic on port 80.

Is there a way to debug this?

Answer (score 0):

1. for your firewall, you can check the current rule with 
   **/etc/init.d/iptables status** command.
2. and you can disable/cleanup your iptables with 
   **/etc/init.d/iptables stop**
3. to check the route to your public ip ,do **tracepath YOUR-PUBLIC-IP**